# USB modem driver OpenWRT: ttyUSB0 getting disconnected

Tags: router, usb, drivers, modem, openwrt

I am trying to use mmx352g modem (Vendor=1c9e ProdID=f000) with my OpenWRT router.

```
root@GL-AR150:/dev# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1c9e:f000 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But I am getting the following log:

```
root@GL-AR150:/dev# dmesg | grep -i usb
[    0.590000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.590000] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.600000] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.070000] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    2.080000] usbcore: registered new interface driver lg-vl600
[    2.080000] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    2.090000] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    6.900000] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    6.910000] ehci-platform ehci-platform: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    6.950000] ehci-platform ehci-platform: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    6.950000] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    6.960000] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    6.970000] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    6.990000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    7.280000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[    7.430000] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    7.440000] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[    8.440000] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   21.120000] usbserial: unknown parameter 'maxSize' ignored
[   21.130000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   21.130000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   21.140000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   21.150000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
[   21.160000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
[   21.170000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: generic converter detected
[   21.170000] usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   21.350000] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[   21.480000] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[   21.510000] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[   21.510000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[   21.520000] usbcore: registered new interface driver huawei_cdc_ncm
[   21.680000] usbcore: registered new interface driver ipheth
[   21.760000] usbcore: registered new interface driver qmi_wwan
[   21.770000] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   21.770000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra
[   21.780000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Sierra USB modem
[   21.790000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra_net
[   21.820000] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   21.820000] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   22.050000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sonixb
[   22.060000] usbcore: registered new interface driver sonixj
[   22.090000] usbcore: registered new interface driver gspca_zc3xx
[   22.240000] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   22.240000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[   22.480000] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
[   31.370000] generic ttyUSB0: generic converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[   31.380000] usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

I am not an expert in linux and I can't understand the log file to detect the problem. It seems that the modem is getting detected `usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0, usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)`

But then getting disconnected at last. `generic ttyUSB0: generic converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0, usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: device disconnected`

I have also added/modified 2 files (60-usb-serial and usb-serial) in /etc/modules.d and edited their contents with

```
usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0xf000 maxSize=4096
```

Here are some other outputs that can be useful:

```
root@GL-AR150:/dev# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 1
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 3.18
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.18.27 ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=ehci-platform
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=f000 Rev= 0.00
S:  Manufacturer=USB Modem
S:  Product=USB Modem
S:  SerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms


root@GL-AR150:/dev# ls | grep tty
tty
ttyATH0
ttyS0
ttyS1
ttyS10
ttyS11
ttyS12
ttyS13
ttyS14
ttyS15
ttyS2
ttyS3
ttyS4
ttyS5
ttyS6
ttyS7
ttyS8
ttyS9
```

The modem seems to be working on its own (seems by looking at the LED flashes. The current flash sequence means it is registered on the network) but OpenWRT can't get the driver to communicate. Can anyone please help regarding this?

Comment: It looks like the USB device is being loaded with generic drivers... Check and see if vendor specific drivers are available for it for your specific distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was how to do the mode switching properly. From usb_modeswitch [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usb_modeswitch):

> On Linux, in most cases the drivers are available as kernel modules, such as "usbserial" or "option". However, the device (WAN dongles) shows up as "usb-storage" by default. usb_modeswitch can send a provided bulk message (most likely a mass storage command) to the device which is known to initiate the mode switching.

On my Linux laptop, the dongle used to work fine. So, I looked at the log messages and found out that the mode switch 'message' is different than than the one being used in OpenWRT.

```
USB_ModeSwitch log from Wed Sep 12 12:19:46 PDT 2018
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
DefaultVendor=  0x1c9e
DefaultProduct= 0xf000
TargetVendor=   0x1c9e
TargetProductList="9000,9603,9605,9607,9900,9a00"
MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
  found USB ID 1c9e:f000
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
Looking for active drivers ...
 OK, driver detached
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
Check success of mode switch for max. 20 seconds ...
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
 Read attributes ...
 All attributes matched
Mode switching was successful, found 1c9e:9605 (USB Modem: USB Modem)
        ...OMITTED FOR CLARITY...
All done, exit
```

OpenWRT uses a utility called [`usbmode`](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/wwan/usb-modeswitching), which seems to be a stripped-down version of the classic usb_modeswitch. The config file is located at `/etc/usb-mode.json`. The default config was not working for me, so I replaced the content of the original file with the following;

```
{
    "messages" : [
            "55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
],
"devices" : {
            "1c9e:f000": {
                    "*": {
                            "t_vendor": 7326,
                            "t_product": [ 38405 ],
                            "msg": [ 0 ],
                            "wait": 5
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Rebooted the router and the dongle was detected properly. Here is the relevant portions from the log:

At [   17.576569] and [   18.653216], it shows up as a storage device. At [   21.384065], it gets disconnected (because of the modeswitch command). And finally at [   22.542980], it is detected as a modem.

```
[   17.576569] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   17.622021] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   17.625508] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   17.726435] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   17.730925] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   17.737547] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   17.878689] xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
[   17.904942] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   18.200614] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[   18.225069] NET: Registered protocol family 24
[   18.248515] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   18.450180] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   18.454525] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
    ...
[   18.653216] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            USBModem Disk             2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[   18.712241] kmodloader: done loading kernel modules from /etc/modules.d/*
[   21.384065] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   21.885051] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ci_hdrc
[   22.542980] option 1-1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   22.548046] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   22.555899] option 1-1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   22.560931] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   22.568813] option 1-1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   22.573936] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   22.581718] option 1-1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[   22.586759] usb 1-1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
```

We can also see that the productID has been changed to 9605 from f000, indicating that the mode switch was successful.

```
root@MrGhosh:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c9e:9605 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

root@MrGhosh:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
...
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=9605 Rev= 0.00
S:  Manufacturer=USB Modem
S:  Product=USB Modem
S:  SerialNumber=1234567890ABCDEF
C:* #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
I:* If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
I:* If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
E:  Ad=84(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=2ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=04(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=4ms
I:* If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=05(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=86(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```